# Windows won't boot after shrinking the partition using Easeus Partition Master and drive space has been used up

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint alongside Windows but didn't allocate enough space for Linux, so I was going to shrink the Windows partition to free up some more space.

I used a program called Easeus Partition Master to shrink the partition. ~200gb was used out of 800gb, so I opted to shrink the partition to about 400gb. The program rebooted the computer and ran from boot mode and then started the shrinking operation.

It said it was 'moving files', it took about 15 minutes to get to 5% so I left it and then noticed it rebooted the computer shortly afterwards. So it probably didn't finish.

The computer booted into Linux since that's the default OS. I then rebooted to get into Windows and I see the spinning icon for a few moments and then it reboots again without getting into the OS. This happens every time I try and boot into Windows now and I'm unable to get in.

From Linux, if I check the C: drive from there it says that ~600gb is used and ~300gb is free. Before I started it was ~200gb used and ~800gb free. So I guess this partition management program has filled up the space trying to move files or something but was unable to finish.

I can at least boot into Linux Mint since that hasn't been affected by this.

Any idea how I can sort this out?

Comment: Can you view the Windows file partition from your Linux machine to verify what is or isn't there? You can also try to use a Windows 10 ISO to launch startup repair options. Either booting into Safe Mode or running ChkDsk. I'd only try to do a repair or recovery of Windows once I verified and/or backed up the files on that partition.

Comment: I think it was a restart loop to continue the operation where partition manager left the task earlier but rebooting straight into linux instead of windows caused this problem. Not sure but I think you won't be able to boot into windows or recovery mode to correct this. Best thing if you have a backup and if not atleast copy all accessible user files and reinstall. Get a windows bootable USB (you can use woeusb on linux mint as well).During installation select upgrade instead of fresh install so that programs and user files are preserved

Comment: Also while creating bootable usb I will suggest you to to make sure windows iso matches the currently installed version of windows or at least close to it (preferably a little higher so there is no compatibility issues).And a lesson never use these third party softwares (always use either freewares or in-built ones)

Comment: Yeah I can still access the windows files through Linux as it mounts the partition. The files I have there seem to be fine. So I will backup my important files from that partition and then create a Windows bootable USB to do a re-install.

Will my Linux partition remain untouched if I do this though? I hear that Windows sometimes messes with boot manager. I'm kind of worried that I might not be  able to get into Linux or Windows if something goes wrong. Also, any idea about all that used up space that this partition manager filled up? It's filled up about 400gb

Comment: You might be able to use a program like du in Linux to check to see what is taking up all the space on that partition. This is why I asked you to check your Windows files though, to make sure nothing crazy happened, like they were all duplicated or something. Whenever dualbooting windows and linux, setting up the boot sequence can be problematic, but it always fixable in my experience. Installing windows will override grub, but then you can use another linux live CD to repair it back. It's a process, but you are sure to learn a few things.